# Need help building the Where() clause in a query to a database

Tags: c#, linq

I'm having problems building the `.Where()` clause for a LINQ query.

I need to return a list of `RegionsResources` from the database for the `cultureName` parameter and `IsActive = true`. If `IsActive = false`, then return the `defaultCultureName` for the matching `Id`.

These are the entities (properties not pertinent are not included for brevity):

```
public class RegionResources
{
    // FYI: Composite-Key (Id, CultureId)
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CultureId { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Culture Culture { get; set; }
}

public class Culture
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CultureName { get; set; }
}
```

Some data examples:

```
1: RegionResources { Id = 1, CultureId = 1, IsActive = true, Name = "Name(en-US)" }
2: RegionResources { Id = 1, CultureId = 2, IsActive = true, Name = "Name(he-IL)" }
3: RegionResources { Id = 2, CultureId = 1, IsActive = true, Name = "Name_2(en-US)" }
4: RegionResources { Id = 2, CultureId = 2, IsActive = FALSE, Name = "Name_2(he-IL)" }
--
1: Culture { Id = 1, CultureName = "en-US" }
2: Culture { Id = 2, CultureName = "he-IL" }
```

Here is the method with a couple of .Where() clauses that don't work as needed:

```
public class GetRegionResources(string cultureName = "he-IL",
                                string defaultCultureName = "en-US")
{
    var query = context.RegionResources

    // This Where() uses '||' and returns ALL that are IsActive=true
    // for both cultureNames
    .Where(r => (r.Culture.CultureName == cultureName && r.IsActive) ||
                r.Culture.CultureName == defaultCultureName)
    // OR
    // This Where() uses '&&' and returns NOTHING (0 records)
    .Where(r => (r.Culture.CultureName == cultureName && r.IsActive) &&
                r.Culture.CultureName == defaultCultureName)
    .ToList();

    return query;
}
```

So requesting:

```
GetReionResources("he-IL", "en-US");
```

Should return the following:

```
2: RegionResources { Id = 1, CultureId = 2, IsActive = true, Name = "Name(he-IL)" }
3: RegionResources { Id = 2, CultureId = 1, IsActive = true, Name = "Name_2(en-US)" }
```

NOTE: Record (3) should be returned and NOT Record (4) because even though the cultureName = he-IL, IsActive = false (not true).

How should the .Where() clause be written? Or, if .Where() shouldn't be used, what would be the correct query?

Thank you.

REVISION TO METHOD: I didn't copy the initial method, but rather retyped it with nominal detail thinking that only the Where() would need to be re-written. I also realized that I made it a class not a method. Here is the actual method.

```
public IPagedList<RegionResources> GetRegionResources(
    string cultureName,
    string defaultCultureName,
    int page,
    int pageSize)
{
    var query = context.RegionResources
        .Where(r => r.Culture.CultureName == cultureName && r.IsActive ||
                    r.Culture.CultureName == defaultCultureName);
    query = query.OrderBy(r => r.Name);
    query = query.Include(r => r.Culture);
    return query.ToPagedList(page, pageSize);
}
```

Sorry to those who put in the time and tried helping based on the initial post. Thanks.

Comment: I suspect if you first find region ID with one query and then run you existing query filtering by regionId and whatever culture name checks you like the code would be easier to understand and likely to do what you want. Later you can try to merge it into single query (probably with some inner join).

Comment: This is a GetList not GetSingle. I need a pagedList using Skip().Take() of regionId's, but for the specified cultureName that IsActive, if it's not Active, then get the defaultCultureName that is always active.

Comment: Did you create the Extended method ToPagedList yourself?

Comment: Yes, I needed a customizable pager for this API, but it pretty much uses the standard Skip().Take().  On the UI side, one of my MVC projects is using  X.PagedList.Mvc.Core where the properties map pretty much the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = context.RegionResources
        .Where(r => (r.Culture.CultureName == cultureName && r.IsActive) ||
                         (r.Culture.CultureName == defaultCultureName && r.Name != "Name(en-US)"))
        .ToList();
```

should return

```
2: RegionResources { Id = 1, CultureId = 2, IsActive = true, Name = "Name(he-IL)" }
3: RegionResources { Id = 2, CultureId = 1, IsActive = true, Name = "Name_2(en-US)" }
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I didn't explain accurately: I NEED the the result from the query to return Records 2 & 3

Comment: @Ronnie You need another condition to filter record 1.

Comment: Yes, I just can't figure how to include the condition... Can you help with the additional conditional statement?

Comment: @Ronnie You can add another condition like this: var query = context.RegionResources
        .Where(r => (r.Culture.CultureName == cultureName && r.IsActive) ||
                         (r.Culture.CultureName == defaultCultureName && r.Name != "Name(en-US)"))
        .ToList();

Comment: Can't specify r.Name. There are many RegionResource records with different Name values for both cultures (en-US and he-IL). I only added 4 in this post as examples. I was thinking maybe something that would specify  'r.Id Count = 1'

Answer (score 0):

What you actually want is **set** the default culture when the culture is InActive. This can be done with a Select. You only want to set it for the inactive so it needs to be a union or Active and Inactive items for that culture.

```
List<Culture> cult = new List<Culture>();
            var c1 = new Culture() { Id = 1, CultureName = "en-US" };
            var c2 = new Culture() { Id = 2, CultureName = "he-IL" };
            cult.Add(c1);
            cult.Add(c2);

            List<RegionResources> rr = new List<RegionResources>();
            rr.Add(new RegionResources() { Id = 1, Culture = c1, IsActive = true, Name = "Name(en-US)" });
            rr.Add(new RegionResources() { Id = 1, Culture = c2, IsActive = true, Name = "Name(he-IL)" });
            rr.Add(new RegionResources() { Id = 2, Culture = c1, IsActive = true, Name = "Name_2(en-US)" });
            rr.Add(new RegionResources() { Id = 2, Culture = c2, IsActive = false, Name = "Name_2(he-IL)" });

            string cultureName = "he-IL";
            var defaultCulture = c1;

            List<RegionResources> result = rr.Where(r => r.Culture.CultureName == cultureName && r.IsActive == true)
                .Union(rr.Where(r => r.Culture.CultureName == cultureName && r.IsActive == false)).Select(x => { x.Culture = defaultCulture; return x; }).ToList();
```

Comment: The List<RegionResources> rr is not static, its in the DB.  I added them as entities to be clear at what I needed from the DB. But maybe there is something there using Union(). I just need an initial list to get from the DB to union.

Comment: Does not matter if on db, use the linq in your code. I only used this as test and for others to have something running.

Comment: I'll try it out.

Comment: In an attempt, I set rr = context.RegionResources(), but it didn't work out because it returns then entire table. There is also Skip.Take and OrderBy in the query. I left it out thinking only the Where() needed to be re-written.

Comment: Edited the question and added the actual method. Thank you for your assistance Aldert.